# Error: could not handle the request

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I'm following a tutorial at https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation#deploy_function_again and executed `gcloud beta functions deploy weatherWebhook --trigger-http`. Google's response seemed to be successful:

> Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...done.
>
> availableMemoryMb: 256 entryPoint: weatherWebhook httpsTrigger:
>
> url: https://[..].cloudfunctions.net/weatherWebhook
>
> labels:   deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
>
> name: projects/[..]/functions/weatherWebhook
>
> serviceAccountEmail: [..]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
>
> sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-[..]
>
> &Expires=1519141082&Signature=[..] status: ACTIVE timeout: 60s
>
> updateTime: '2018-02-20T15:08:02Z' versionId: '3'

However when I open the URL in the browser I receive the following error message:

> Error: could not handle the request

Did I miss something? How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have your tried running "gcloud beta functions describe weatherWebhook"? The error seems to state either the Cloud Function wasn't successful or perhaps the Cloud Functions API isn't enabled for your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the tutorial for dialogflow.com used broken. I had to setup a Node.js server and everything in order to find out what the cause was which was not helpful. Error messages are *not* forwarded from Google Cloud. Unfortunately I can not recommend using either service.

```
C:\Node.js\run-func:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

If someone *is* having a similar issue here are some troubleshooting suggestions:

- Check the network panel in the browser's developer tools; the dialogflow website was returning HTTP 400 errors and those errors disappeared the next day using the exact same code (their website is *not* marked as beta).
- Ensure you're uploading the correct file (I was though still worth mentioning).
- If the server is returning an error by default presume your (or whoever's) code works *locally*. I worked to verify the code from dialogflow and *then* was going to contact either service.